# Map between endomorphism operads

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, operads

Let $A$ and $B$ be alegebras of any kind (the example that I have in mind is the underlying module of a graded operad) and consider its endomorphism operads $\mathrm{End}_A$ and $\mathrm{End}_B$, where $\mathrm{End}_X(n) = \hom(X^{\otimes n}, X)$. Given a map $f:A\to B$ I would like to be able to define a map $\mathrm{End}_A\to \mathrm{End}_B$ (or contravariantly if that was possible).

However, even for $n=1$ this only seems to be possible if $f$ is an isomorphism, since we would need to define a map $B\to B$ from a map $A\to A$, and this would generallyv be possible to achieve by means of $B\xrightarrow{f^{-1}} A\to A\xrightarrow{f}B$.

For general $n$ the situation is the same, as we would have to take an $n$-fold tensor product of $f^{-1}$.

Are there any more general conditions (either on the algebras or the map) for some kind of algebras where it is possible to stablish such maps even if $f$ is not an isomorphism (or more generally if $A$ and $B$ are not isomorphic)?

I know the question is very broad since I am not being very specific about the category in which I'm working, but I am really interested in any possibility and I may even have to define a category according to the suitable notion of morphism that allows the above maps.

Comment: Why do you have any hope that this would work when f is not an isomorphism?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I am not very hopeful, but I thought that maybe there is some more indirect construction of the induced map that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If in addition to $f$ you have a morphism $g: B \to A$ then you can define a morphism of operads $H: \textrm{End}_A \to \textrm{End}_B$ as follows. Given $a: A^{\otimes n}\to A$, define $H(a)$ as the composite $f \circ a \circ (g, \dots, g)$.

This situation appears, for example, when you have homotopy retracts (homotopy transfer diagrams). In the differential graded context, a homotopy retract is the data of two dg-modules $(A,d)$ and $(B,d)$ together with cochain morphisms $p: A \to B$ and $i: B \to A$ both of degree zero, and $h: A \to A$ of degree $-1$, satisfying that $pi=\textrm{id}$ and $\partial h = ip - \textrm{id}$. In this context, a somewhat more elaborated morphism than the one I described on the first paragraph yields the Homotopy Transfer Theorem.